# How can I execute a git alias from a specific directory, not the root of the repo

Tags: git

Git seems to execute all the aliases from the root of the repo. You can see this by using the following alias:

```
test = !pwd
```

or even

```
test2 = "!f() { pwd ;}; f"
```

which will both display the directory of the root of the repo, not the subdirectory that you are in.

How can I make an alias that executes from the directory that you are in, not the root?

Comment: More information that might be useful - using git's internal evaluation of aliases: `pwd = rev-parse --show-prefix` is correct, but when you use bash: `test = !git rev-parse --show-prefix`, it's evaluated from the root (and so is always empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the variable `$GIT_PREFIX`. For example:

```
test = !echo $GIT_PREFIX
```

or a more valid use-case:

```
cat-from = "!f() { git show $1:\"$GIT_PREFIX$2\" ;}; f"
```

which can be used to cat a file from a particular branch without checking it out: `git cat-from master foo.txt`

I found this by looking in the source code here: https://github.com/git/git/blob/35f6318d44379452d8d33e880d8df0267b4a0cd0/t/t1020-subdirectory.sh#L131

Please add an edit/comment/answer if you can find where this is documented.