# cwd at root of git repo when executing git alias?

Tags: git

I was writing a command to be able to compare a file to it's previous modification when I found out that the cwd is set to the root of the repo before execution of the alias.  This means a command like:

```
git diffprev path/filename.txt
```

will only work if `path` is relative to the git repo root.  If not, it will not find the `filename.txt` file, which is quite annoying.  Is there a way I can get around this problem?

Example alias:

```
diffprev = "!pwd; echo"
```

Will show the root of repo and the files passed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I execute a git alias from a specific directory, not the root of the repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49759529/how-can-i-execute-a-git-alias-from-a-specific-directory-not-the-root-of-the-rep)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+alias+root